# How to open pop on a click of link in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.3

hi i want to know that how can i show pop when a link or say button is clicked.
 i know how to display pop up on over a click in PHP but am completely unaware about it in magento coz i have never tried that.

in case of displaying popup in php we can use this code

```
<a href="link"  target="popup"  onclick="window.open('yourLink','popup','width=600,height=600,scrollbars=no,resizable=no'); return false;">
    Open Popup
</a>
```

can i use same code for magento also

do i have to use any custom module to achieve this or it is possible thorough .phtml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code in your phtml file for Magento popup model

```
<a id="click-me" href="link">
    Open Popup
</a>
<div id="popup-modal" class="popup" style="display: none;">
    test
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function( $, modal ) {
    var options = {
        type: 'popup',
        responsive: true,
        innerScroll: true,
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Continue',
            class: 'mymodal1',
            click: function () {
                this.closeModal();
            }
        }]
    };

    var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
    $("#click-me").on('click',function(){
        $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
    });

});
</script>
```